# How can I use .htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Trying to get

```
www.example.com
```

to go directly to

```
www.example.com/store
```

I have tried multiple bits of code and none work.

What I've tried:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /samle/%1/$1 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 306):

You can use a rewrite rule that uses **^$** to represent the root and rewrite that to your /store directory, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /store [L]
```

Comment: If `/store` is a physical subdirectory then you will need to append a trailing slash on the `RewriteRule` _substitution_, otherwise mod_dir will trigger a 301 external redirect to append the trailing slash and `/store/` will be exposed to your users. Also, the regex `^$` won't "appear to" match if you have a `DirectoryIndex` document (eg. `index.html`) in the root directory (nothing "appears to" happen) since mod_dir will issue an internal subrequest for the index document _after_ the initial rewrite. To get around both these issues, change it to `RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /store/ [L]`.

Comment: If you may add a real page at the root level at later date you should use a temporary redirect by replacing the `[L]` with `[R=302,L]`

Answer (score 188):

I was surprised that nobody mentioned this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /store/
```

Basically, it redirects the root and only the root URL.
The answer originated from [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/9992/how-to-get-apache2-to-redirect-to-a-subdirectory)

Comment: this is simple and by far best answer

Comment: @iamnabink That depends if you want an _internal rewrite_ (as stated in the question and as answered by the earlier answers) or a 302-temporary _external redirect_ (as stated here). It also depends whether you have existing mod_rewrite directives, as the OP clearly has. So, in the context of the _question_ it's not the "best answer". YMMV.

Comment: Add this line in the `.htaccess` file under the web app root (for e.g `/var/www/html_docs/.htaccess`) if you don't have access to server configuration file. Else you can modify the server configuration, see more https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Answer (score 118):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ store [L]
```

If you want an external redirect (which cause the visiting browser to show the redirected URL), set the `R` flag there as well:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /store [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Both the sample.com and www.sample.com redirect to www.sample.com/store. That's just what I wanted.

Thank you Gumbo, and everyone who answered. I learned a lot reading your responses and appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I'm curious, will this show `www.example.com` as the URI after the redirect? If not, how would it be changed to do so?

Comment: ♦ - And why would your solution be better than Sander's down below? I notice your final line is the same, but if that is all that is needed, why include the `RewriteCond` and the first `RewriteRule`?

Comment: if this code used, can you type in your browser exmple.com/../aboveSubDir?

Comment: @GamErix This would be resolved to `/aboveSubDir` by either the browser or by the server.

Comment: @Gumbo, Could you please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937873/how-to-remove-a-subdirectory-from-the-url-when-forwarding-to-sudirectory??

Comment: Should be the top solution, as it also shows how to external redirect as well.

Comment: My god after days, `RewriteRule ^$ web [L]` is what worked to redirect my symfony root (http://www.example.com/agenda) to its web subfolder where the app.php DirectoryIndex resides (http://www.example.com/agenda/web/[etc]). I'd love to take off that web bit but work for another day.

Comment: Where should I add this?

Answer (score 82):

Here is what I used to redirect to a subdirectory. This did it invisibly and still allows through requests that match an existing file or whatever.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdir/index.php [L]
```

Change out site.com and subdir with your values.

Answer (score 42):

To set an invisible redirect from root to subfolder, You can use the following RewriteRule in /root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

The rule above will internally redirect the browser from :

- http://example.com/

to

- http://example.com/subfolder

And

- http://example.com/foo

to

- http://example.com/subfolder/foo

while the browser will stay on the root folder.

Comment: This answer works well if you need a redirect that is invisible to the user.

Answer (score 26):

Another alternative if you want to rewrite the URL and hide the original URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/$1 [L]
```

With this, if you for example type `http://www.example.com/product.php?id=4`, it will transparently open the file at `http://www.example.com/store/product.php?id=4` but without showing to the user the full url.

Comment: Add `QSA` (query string append) to `[L]` (`[L, QSA]`) if you want query strings carried-over to the rewritten url.

Comment: @chaiguy thank's for the tip, but on my server it worked without QSA (but I agree it's probably better to append QSA). Maybe it's because of some special config of my apache server?

Comment: This method for me, example.com shows content from example.com/store  transparently but example.com/test redirects to example.com/store/test, showing the url

Comment: @devios1 You don't need the `QSA` flag in this example since there is no query string in the _substitution_ string. When there is no query string in the _substitution_ the original query string from the request is passed through by default.

Comment: This example will result in a rewrite-loop (500 error response) unless you also have another `.htaccess` file in the `/store` subdirectory that also contains mod_rewrite directives (since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, thus preventing a rewrite-loop).

Comment: What is the key fragment in this example to make it redirect without changing the URL? I always thought that I need a proxy for that. How does this work?

Answer (score 16):

This seemed the simplest solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/store [R=301,L]
```

I was getting redirect loops with some of the other solutions.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the above solutions are correct but they are all missing the transparency of the redirection.

In my case, when visiting **www.example.com** I wanted to get redirected to the subdirectory **/store** but without updating the URL to **www.example.com/store**. (all I want is to get the page code form that directory). If that is your case the solution below works perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/$1 [L]
```

source: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Transparently_redirect_your_root_directory_to_a_subdirectory

Comment: What should I change if I needed that www.example.com got redirected to www.othersite.com/store without updating the URL? I tried but was unable to adapt your code

Comment: I tried to to change the last line to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherpage.com/subfolder/$1 [L]` but it updates the URL

Comment: All you need is to replace the words `example` and `store`.

Comment: I didn't explain quite well. I own `example.com` and `otherpage.com` domains. When I visit `example.com` I want that the contents from `otherpage.com/subfolder` to be displayed, without updating the URL

Comment: Well my answer above does not do that. Try posting a new question.

Answer (score 8):

I don't understand your question...

If you want to redirect every request to a subfolder:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ shop/$1 [L,QSA]

http://www.example.com/* -> wwwroot/store/*
```

If you want to redirect to a subfolder which has the domain name

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L,QSA]

http://www.example.com/* -> wwwroot/example.com/*
```

Comment: I like your code `([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$` to reserve domain as subfolder name.

Answer (score 7):

I have found that in order to avoid circular redirection, it is important to limit the scope of redirection to root directory.
I would have used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/store [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 5):

Two ways out of possible solutions to achieve this are:
1. Create a `.htaccess` file in root folder as under (just replace example.com and my_dir with your corresponding values):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_dir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_dir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

2. Use RedirectMatch to only redirect the root URL “/” to another folder or URL,

   RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.example.com/my_dir

Answer (score 4):

Formerly I use the following code which is work correctly to redirect root URL of each of my domains/subdomains to their correspondence subdirectories which are named exactly as the sub/domain it self as below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.domain1.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subs/sub1.domain1.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subs/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.domain1.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subs/sub1.domain2.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subs/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.domain2.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subs/sub1.domain2.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subs/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.domain2.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subs/sub2.domain2.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subs/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA]
```

However when I want to add another subs or domains then it will need to be added in the above code. It should be much more convenient to simplify it to work **like  wildcard (*)** as below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subs/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subs/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA]
```

So whenever another subdomains/domains is added as long as the subdomain name has a prefix of **sub** (like: sub3.domain1.com, sub1.domain3.com etc.) the code will remain valid.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main problems with the code you posted are:

- the first line matches on a host beginning with strictly sample.com, so www.sample.com doesn't match.
- the second line wants at least one character, followed by www.sample.com which also doesn't match (why did you escape the first w?)
- none of the included rules redirect to the url you specified in your goal (plus, sample is misspelled as samle, but that's irrelevant).

For reference, here's the code you currently have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\www.sample\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /samle/%1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

One can use **[Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)** too for this purpose

```
Redirect 301 / www.example.com/store
```

Or **[Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)** for mapping

```
Alias / /store
```

**Edit:** mod_alias is only applicable in httpd.conf.

Refrences

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html

Comment: You can't use `Redirect` here, it will result in a redirect loop. (You could use `RedirectMatch`, as mentioned in other answers.) Also, the `Alias` directive will need a trailing slash on the _file-path_ (2nd argument), ie. `Alias / /store/`, otherwise a request for `/foo` will map to `/storefoo` instead of `/store/foo`.

Answer (score 2):

A little googling, gives me these results:

> RewriteEngine On
>  RewriteBase
>   /
>  RewriteRule ^index.(.*)?$
>   http://domain.com/subfolder/
>   [r=301]
>
> This will redirect any attempt to
>   access a file named index.something to
>   your subfolder, whether the file
>   exists or not.

Or try this:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
>   !^www.sample.com$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$
>   %{HTTP_HOST}/samlse/$1 [R=301,L]

I haven't done much redirect in the .htaccess file, so I'm not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 1):

try to use below lines in htaccess

Note: you may need to check what is the name of the default.html

default.html is the file that load by default in the root folder.

`RewriteEngine`

`Redirect /default.html http://example.com/store/`

Answer (score 1):

you just add this code into your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will try the subdir if the file doesn't exist in the root. Needed this as I moved a basic .html website that expects to be ran at the root level and pushed it to a subdir. Only works if all files are flat (no .htaccess trickery in the subdir possible). Useful for linked things like css and js files.

```
# Internal Redirect to subdir if file is found there.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-s
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/%{REQUEST_URI} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the original question not by pointing out another possible syntax (there are many amongst the other answers) but by pointing out something I have once had to deal with, that took me a while to figure out:

> What am I doing wrong?

There is a possibility that %{HTTP_HOST} is not being populated properly, or at all. Although, I've only seen that occur in only one machine on a shared host, with some custom patched apache 2.2, it's a possibility nonetheless.