# RewriteRule match root dir?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

There appears to be some historic confusion on existing answers in SO on the exact regex to use to match a request for the root directory. eg: ^/$ , ^$ or ^/?$

See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766443/use-mod-rewrite-to-rewrite-root-to-another-path) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory).
So, let's clarify it

Question:

> What is currently valid, 'for 2018' way to match a request to the root dir?

**Single case test (with chrome)**

I did run a quick test and it seems (with chrome at least) to always match ^$ regardless of how the url was typed, Including /?test. This last bit makes me think the server config matters too.

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /index-with-slash.html [L,R=301,NE] <-- no hits
RewriteRule ^$ /index-wo-slash.html [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: To match against Root dir in `htaccess` context we use `^$` and `^/$` is used on server.config or virtual host context.

Comment: reply and explain the difference in scope if there is any and you get the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^/?$` will match both cases. No need to reinvent the wheel.

If you are concerned about regex being heavy on the resources, you likely would not be using Apache anyways.