# Redirect to another folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I read this [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htacces-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory) and i'm trying to achieve the same things.

The solution with most up votes was:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ store [L]
```

Now, looking at the comments it seems to be working good.
The problem is that I'd like not to hardcode any path (as instead provided above "www.example.com"). I'd like that my `.htaccess` inside `projectname/` redirects to `projectname/public/` despite what the real server host is. So that if I put `projectname/` inside the root server of `www.pinco.com` it redirects to `www.pinco.com/projectname/public/` but it shows `www.pinco.com/projectname/`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you found is actually doing two different things.

```
# This is actually just redirecting all http://example.com/somepage/
# to http://www.example.com/somepage/, to ensure all URLs have the www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second rewrite is what will help you achieve what you're trying to do.

```
# This redirect all requests for http://example.com -> http://example.com/newdir
# If you are looking to redirect the request, so the URL contains directory name,
# you can change the [L] to [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /newdir [L]

# If your concerned about direct access to a particular page without the sub-dir 
# you will want to add something like this
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newdir
RewriteRule (.*) /newdir$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, in that case, you won't have to be concerned with domain that the application is running on.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line, and :

```
RewriteBase /projectname
```

And you stay inside the project.