# Setting up custom sub domain linking to another server page

Tags: php, url, dns, subdomain, url-routing

I have a php application app.example.com and I would like businesses to have the ability to link a sub domain back to there page on my server.
For Example:
app.business.com go to app.example.com/profile/business (as index of sub domain)
I understand DNS records pointing to my server however I do not now how to manage this on my end. Meaning how does my server know to server the correct page.

Comment: Maybe you can use .htaccess file to do it ? But it might not be the best idea... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214300/load-new-site-from-subdirectory-as-index