# Map a second domain name to a specific method

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have two domain names pointing to the same server, example.com and myapp.com.  I want all requests to http://example.com/params (with zero or more params) to be equivalent to requesting http://myapp.com/controller/method/params.  I don't care whether or not the URL includes "www".

Here is my progress so far.  Requests for http://example.com/param are not being rewritten as requests for http://example.com/controller/method/param.  To clarify, a request for http://example.com/login takes me to the login page accessible from http://myapp.com/login, not the page accessible from http://myapp.com/controller/method/login.  It seems there is something wrong with my first rewrite condition, but I can't figure out what.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller/method/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm using CodeIgniter which is why I am routing all requests through index.php.

I have been playing around with the code above but have not had any luck.  Am I on the right track?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your assets have absolute links, or relative links?

Comment: They are all relative links.  If it makes any difference, the functionality I am trying to map the URL to is going to perform a redirect so it's not a problem that the assets aren't loaded.

Comment: You'll have to set your assets URLs as absolute links.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase my original question.  The problem I am having isn't that the assets aren't loading but that example.com is not routing to the correct page.

Comment: the rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller/method/$1 [L]` should be the last

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the forward slash before controller?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller/method/$1
```

Comment: I get the same results whether or not there is a forward slash before "controller."

Comment: also I think you need the ^ in front of example.com

Comment: also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory