# Rewrite .htaccess to subdirectory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite an URL, so when I type

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php
```

is the same as

```
http://mydomain.com/subdomain/index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to handle `index.php` then following will work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|)$ subdomain/$1 [L]
```

However if you want to redirect every request `subdomain folder` then following will work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!subdomain/).*$ subdomain%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: 2nd rule: You have missed 2nd closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /subdomain [L]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1328357/956397

Answer (score 0):

For all files

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /subdomain/$1 [NC]
```