# Redirect a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've installed my wordpress site in a folder and now I only can reach it via: [domainname]/wordpress.

Is it possible to redirect my site to [domainname]?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and can be done in two steps:

1. Change Site Address Option
2. Modify index.php

Details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory on the paragraph **Using a pre-existing subdirectory install**

Answer (score 1):

Move Wordpress to your webroot:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#On_Your_Existing_Server