# Changing all my website links: what is the best way?

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

I need to change all the links(2455) in my site.

There will be a problem when visitors come from Google (using the old links) as the page will be `404 page not found`

I want to redirect the old links to the new version of the page. For example:

Old links:

```
http://example.com/hotel/13234
http://example.com/hotel/132
http://example.com/hotel/323
http://example.com/page/about_us
http://example.com/page/contact
```

New links: (add "blog" ) after domain

```
http://example.com/blog/hotel/13234
http://example.com/blog/hotel/132
http://example.com/blog/page/about_us
http://example.com/blog/hotel/323

...
...
...
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect them to the new `Location` with

```
header('Location: /blog' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

If you use PHP version >= 5.4.0, you can also send a proper HTTP status code 301 (moved permanently) with

```
http_response_code(301);
```

When you want to use `.htaccess` you can redirect with [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule .* /blog$0 [L,R=301]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive prevents rewriting URLs, which already start with `/blog`. Otherwise you will get an endless recursion.
The `RewriteRule` directive prefixes all URLs with `/blog`, doesn't apply further rules [`L`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) and sends HTTP status code 301 [`R=301`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r).

For this to work, these directives must be allowed in `.htaccess`. You can use the same directives in your main conf file or in a virtual host context.

Comment: the old page doesn't work , Can doing it .htaccess? every link to my site will redirect , and add blog after domain

Comment: sorry for my bad English

Comment: You have a chicken before the egg issue. If the files are moved to a *blog* subdirectory there will be no file to place this code.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule $ /blog [L,R=301]
```

This will prefix all links with `blog` and permanently redirect them.