# How Change Subdomain Root Folder to Public_html via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, root

I have a subdomain that I want to make the root folder to "Public_html",
for example, my root subdomain is

```
- /public_html/subdomain
```

So I want to change that path to just /public_html/ for my subdomain. I know it can be done with .htaccess, but I dont know how to do it. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want, but here are my two answers:

**Answer 1**: You want your `DocumentRoot` to point to `public_html`

In this case add/change the `DocumentRoot` in your (virtual) host config of your webserver (I'm assuming you're using Apache, which would be `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` or `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` or even `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yourhost`)

**Answer 2**: You want to redirect from your `subdomain` folder to the root of `public_html`

This is not possible via a simple `RewriteRule` due to the fact, that your host is pointing to the `subdomain` folder. The other way round would possible (redirecting from `public_html` to `subdomain`).

What you can to is to create a symbolic link from `subdomain` which points to `public_html` or a file in it - but I don't recommend this.

Furthermore resources:

- [A brief description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory) on how to forward to a subfolder using Rewrite rules
- [Another brief description](http://www.serverschool.com/dedicated-servers/apaches-documentroot-directive/) about the `DocumentRoot`