# I need to remove /en from all URLs, would like to use .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, joomla1.5, multilingual

Using Joomla and trying to stop using JoomFish, but for the time we did use it, other sites linked to our pages as "basedomain.org/en/everypage". Now those links go to 404 errors.

How do I use .htaccess to rewrite or redirect all requests for basedomain.org/en/everypage to basedomain.org/everypage??

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

Once you've confirmed it works, change 302 to 301. (301 is very hard to debug because browsers cache it)

Or, use a `RedirectMatch` (simpler, and no need to enable the RewriteEngine):

```
RedirectMatch permanent /en/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

(replace www.example.com with your own domain)