# codeigniter default upload directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to upload code igniter library to my server. I want to use views on my account root folder like `www.mysite.com/someview/` not `mysite.com/ci/someview`

Is it possible to upload code igniter library to separated folder like /ci/ and still use views on my root account.

update:
How to setup .htacces file knowing that code igniter library is at the /public_html/ci/ folder?

THanks

Comment: Yes, use `.htaccess` and modify your rewrite rules.

Comment: that was quick, thanks

Comment: @RudiVisser question is updated, can you please point me how to write htaccess file

Comment: You might try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/990405/844726