# MediaWiki and Apache2 URL issues

Tags: apache2, mediawiki

i'm new to LAMP and MediaWiki.

To go to my mediawiki i have to type in `domain-name.com/wiki`.

When i type in `domain-name.com`, i go to the apache's index page.

How to make root-url direct me to the wiki page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added one line in my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://domain-name.com/wiki/
```

And it works)

Answer (score 2):

From http://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

```
# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

This should go after your short URL rules. If you have no short URL setup, simply

```
RewriteRule ^$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

should do the trick (see 
 [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory))