# .htaccess redirect to www in subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm having trouble tro redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com` **and** it's subdomain to `www.test.example.com` to `test.example.com` 
And currently i'm using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Try this link similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

You will need one rule for main domain and another for sub domains:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.([a-z]{2,4})$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```