# http://localhost:80 class not registered

Tags: apache, windows-7, wamp, bitnami

I installed Bitnami wamp stack, and, though my installation is reachable by http:// [nameofmylaptop]/site , i have the following error each time I launch apache :

**http://localhost:80
Class not registered**

I can't find anything relating to this..

Any help ? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried: http://localhost/site, it could be that since your website is in a subfolder called site, localhost root directory has nothing to display

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: localhost/site, it could be that since your website is in a subfolder called site, localhost root directory has nothing to display.

*@Husman Yeah it works.*

Theres your problem then, there is nothing in the root folder, you can have an apache redirect to take you from localhost to localhost/site, and that should fix your issue.

There are multiple ways to redirect:

- use a server side script (index.php)
- use [.htaccess rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

  `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ /site[L]`
- use apache config `httpd.conf` to redirect from one folder to another

  Redirect permanent / http://git.example.com/git/
     ...

Comment: Actually, BitNami VMs always have something configured to work out of the box, and root directory has a page to display. So, it's not the problem.