# Routing Issue want to display domain name even index.aspx is called

Tags: c#, routes, global, asp.net-routing

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Main", "", "~/index.aspx");
```

thats the route I mapped on index page..
when I call the url with index.aspx it displays like

```
www.abc.com/index.aspx
```

but I want it to show

```
www.abc.com
```

even when index.aspx is called

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Comment: well @MichaC im talking about C# not php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding my comment, URL Rewrite is also available in IIS and Asp.net. So you can potentially use it.

Another solution would be to redirect to your route. The route alone doesn't change the URL, it just allows you to access the resource via the defined route.

You can redirect to the route though, which will rewrite the URL on the client
For example like this:

```
        if (Request.Path != "/")
        {
            Context.Response.RedirectToRoute("Main");
        }
```

This is very simplified and might not work in all scenarios, so please be very careful.