# .htaccess rewrite with subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite (not redirect) all url's of my site to a sub-directory of my site. For example:

```
http://example.com/example
```

would load the following:

```
http://example.com/public/example
```

Though, requesting `http://example.com/public` should **not** load the contents from `public/public` but from `/`.

Answers I've found on SO either do the above with redirect (which I don't want) or doesn't account for the special case above.

*EDIT: further clarification:*

I want every request on my site to go load under the `public` folder, but without being visible to the visitor. So requesting `http://example.com/index.php` will load the file from `http://example.com/public/index.php`. The url in the browser remains unchanged for the user.

Comment: check this u will get the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory

Comment: @SRK, tried a few answers there, but they redirect.

Comment: if you enter http://example.com/example this it will not redirect only show http://example.com/public/example  right???

Comment: Example.com/example would load the default file from /public/example. No redirect visible to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!public).+)$ /public/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite all requests from root to /public dir.

Comment: This seems to work for `http://example.com` but `http://www.example.com`  doesn't.

Comment: www or non www is not part of the code I provided. Please check your other rules there.