# change to https and redirect to subfolder rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do two things here:

1. redirect to a sub-folder

   redirect http://www.something.com/some/page.html 
   or 
   https://www.something.com/some/page.html 
   to 
   https://www.something.com/subfolder/some/page.html
2. redirect http to https

   redirect 
   http://www.something.com/subfolder/some/page.html 
   to 
   https://www.something.com/subfolder/some/page.html

And I want to do both of them in the same .htaccess file

I have been able to redirect to subfolder by the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} something.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.something.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

And then I am trying to do both of them; i.e. http to https(only if http request comes) and redirect to subfolder by the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} something.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.something.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

But it's not working.
What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

When using @starkeen's solution; i.e.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I am expecting the following as result:

> https://www.example.com/subfolder/brands/omega.html

when I give any of the following:

```
http://example.com/brands/omega.html OK
https://example.com/brands/omega.html OK

http://www.example.com/brands/omega.html OK
https://www.example.com/brands/omega.html OK

http://example.com/subfolder/brands/omega.html WRONG
http://www.example.com/subfolder/brands/omega.html WRONG
```

But the last two are redirecting to

> https://www.example.com/subfolder/

Comment: Here is an answer for redirection to https => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www   and here for subfolder => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory

Comment: Do you want to redirect html files only or everything from root to sub?

Comment: My redirection is working fine, what I need is to make both of them to work together in a single .htaccess file

Comment: @starkeen everything from root to sub with the original parameters

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rule to do both the tasks in a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:subfolder)?(/.*)?$ https://www.example.com/subfolder$1 [NE,L,R=302,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
#--Http ==>https--#
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#--exclude the destination to avoid redirect loop--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
#--redirect /foo to /subfolder/foo--#
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.something.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Clear your browser'cache before testing this redirect.

Comment: http : // www.example.com/subfolder/some/page.html redirects to https : // www.example.com/subfolder/

Comment: http : // www.example.com/subfolder/some/page.html should redirect to https : // www.example.com/subfolder/some/page.html notice the change to https

Comment: http://example.com/brands/omega.html OK
https://example.com/brands/omega.html OK

http://www.example.com/brands/omega.html OK
https://www.example.com/brands/omega.html OK

http://example.com/subfolder/brands/omega.html WRONG
http://www.example.com/subfolder/brands/omega.html WRONG

Comment: @Subrata what do you mean by "wrong"? Isnt the redirection working as expected?

Comment: Check this in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/gQzhi81x            In the last two cases it is redirecting to https : / / example.com/subfolder/