# How to redirect https to http only in subfolder hidden

Tags: php, laravel

How to redirect all link HTTPS to HTTP in subfolder hidden by using mod_rewrite

For example, **https://homepage.com/public** to **http://homepage.com/public** with public is hidden URL

Comment: Please search the site for similar questions before creating a new question; this has already been asked/answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change to https and redirect to subfolder rule in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008195/change-to-https-and-redirect-to-subfolder-rule-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Note, This site has similar questions with accepted answers!