# Can a redirect take part of old URL to create new one?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to write a rule to transform a group of URLs.  Two examples

1. ```
   /catalog/product/view/id/4411/s/tall-slim-vase/category/186/
   ```

   should become

   ```
   /tall-slim-vase.html
   ```
2. ```
   /catalog/product/view/id/4449/s/cream-rose-basket/category/209/
   ```

   should become

   ```
   /cream-rose-basket.html
   ```

I have many URLs like this.  Can I rewrite all of them using a single rule?

Comment: I think this is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You take the part between `/s` and `/category/` ? 
Regular expressions will help you in this. You can use something like [RegexTester](https://regex101.com/) to test your code and examples.

The rule may be something like:

`"/catalog/product/view/id/####/s"{stuff you need}"/category/###/"`
Then you take the {stuff you need} and add `.html` to it