# Root keeps redirecting url to non existing file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I was playing around with my htaccess file a bit and now every time I go to the root of my website it adds: `/home/websitename/public_html/index.html`

It is very annoying since I don't have any rule that says it should do this, index.html doesn't even exist on my host. What can I do about it?

My htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on

#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#Cross site access toestaan
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"

#Websitename

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule         ^info/(.*).html catlisting.php?alias=$1 [L]
#SUBCAT
RewriteRule         ^catalogus/(.*)/(.*).html cataloguslisting.php?alias_hoofd=$1&alias_sub=$2 [L]
#HOOFDCAT
RewriteRule         ^catalogus/(.*).html cataloguslisting.php?alias=$1 [L]


RewriteRule         ^offerte.html/(.*)/ /offerte.php?items=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^nieuws/(.*).html nieuws.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^producten/(.*).html product2.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^lp/(.*).html lp.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^(.*).html content.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

I was playing around a bit with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory) (2nd one) because of an issue I had. I added [R=301,L] to a rule and now I can't get it back to how it was.