# URL Mapping in php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

i am working on project and need to map the url.

For exmaple: 
current url is:

```
www.xyz.com/course-details.php?id=15
```

and i want to change this url in :

```
www.xyz.com/study-in-countryname.php
```

Comment: any one is there who help me in this

Comment: You should use .htaccess. See [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/990392/5104748)

Comment: You Should Google it for changing the routes and paths and you have to change it into .htacess file