# angular 2 xampp server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular, xampp

I'm trying to set my server im xampp to run an application with the angular 2 quickstart. so far I download the quickstart project to folder in the htdocs/project, set the httpd-vhosts.conf to the folder

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName angular2Teste.com
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/src"

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/src">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

with this I'm able to open the project in the browser with the url angular2teste.com. the problem is that the angular quickstart project is set to have the node modules in the parent folder

```
-project
--node_modules
--src
---index.html
```

as far as I can tell I will need a .htaccess in my directory to set the index.html as root file to all the angular route calls, but also to redirect all the calls from the node_modules to the parent folder but I'm struggle with this, .htaccess is not my strong. 
Any ideias as I can set the .htaccess file?

Comment: Using `.htaccess` is not mandatory you can do all your configuration in `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to get this thing working thanks to this post [answare from Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5793784/347903)

I don't understand very well the logic behind all of this but it's working fine .
I just had to change the root of my project to the parent folder (Project)