# PHP - Htaccess redirect and rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Currenty I have urls like this

```
www.mysite.com/index.php
www.mysite.com/test1/index.php
www.mysite.com/sample2/index.php
... many links
```

Now I removed directory structure and moved to

```
www.mysite.com/index.php
www.mysite.com/test1.php
www.mysite.com/sample2.php
... many links
```

Now I want to hide `.php` and add `/` so that old `href links` stays same like
`www.mysite.com/test1/` ?

After rewriting, if the url is `www.mysite.com/test1/index.php`, how to ingnore `index.php` at the end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Comment: How are rewriting those urls? Please post your code