# how to 301 redirect from root domain to a page with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i am trying to auto 301 redirect from domain.com to domain.com/v2
ive tried this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /v2/ [NC,L]
```

also tried

```
Redirect 301 / /v2/
```

i get the error 'site has tried to redirect you too many times'

is there any way to do this?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a write rule with ***^$*** representing the root of the site and rewrite it to the selected folder

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /v2/
```

it redirects the root and only the root URL.

or also you can use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /v2[L]
```

If you want external redirection(301) you can use **R** flag

```
RewriteRule ^$ /v2[L,R=301]
```

**Another way to use it with RewriteEngine**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ v2 [L]
```

Original [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152129/2872775)

I hope I've helped

Answer (score 2):

Untested but this should redirect both domain.com and www.domain.com to the v2 subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ v2 [L]
```

*You need to replace example.com with your actual domain because of posting restrictions.*

I suppose you have an endless redirect because you are not matching the end of the domain string with `$`. Redirection should only take place at the root domain.