# Apache Reverse Proxy Configuration Changes

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Need some help with Apache Proxy configuration.
My application is available at 8080 at below path.
`http://localhost:8080/HotelOperations`

My current configuration is set as below.

```
ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

With this configuration I am able to access my application at port 80, however, I have to pass `/HotelOperations` to it. I want to be able to access it without `/HotelOperations`.

Accessible at `http://localhost/HotelOperations`
Desirable at `http://localhost`

Any help please.

Comment: Won't a redirect on top of this configuration do the job? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/

Comment: Well, It would. I have instead created a index.html with javascript in it to re-direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to re-write URLs. It's miserable. You have to parse and re-write every HTTP header and every document to do the replacement.

Best to change your application's context path from `/HotelOperations` to  `/` by re-naming the context to `ROOT`.