# How do I install MyBB on Google App engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud, mybb

I have a project on app engine that I control locally. The thing I want to do is install a MyBB forum on my php app. My default url is https://plains.cc but I want the forums to be at https://plains.cc/forums/index.php. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the htacess configuration file to redirect the traffic to a different path, as shown in these articles [[1]](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)[[2]](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/redirects/)[[3]](https://serverfault.com/questions/9992/how-to-get-apache2-to-redirect-to-a-subdirectory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

However, you can use rewriting rules instead, as shown in this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). The apache config file for the virtual host is usually located at “/etc/apache2/apache2.conf” or depending on how MyBB set things up, in a separate file within /etc/apache2 that is included in the main apache2.conf file.

Let me know if it helps.