# htaccess redirect issue: Want all ajax request from root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]*)\.html$ /cat.php?p1=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /cat.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /cat.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [L]
```

I have created this htaccess and it works fine.
But the next problem is in jquery ajax url parameters `url:"ajax/la.php"` in cat.php. it should redirect from root folder not subfolder 
go like this `public_html/ajax/la.php...`

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with

> url:"/ajax/la.php"

if I've understood correct.

Comment: thanks ! its works ! but it goes in cat folder cat/la?m=sda...where la.php file located in root folder not in cat folder ... any solution ? thanks

Comment: oh yes ! it work also . i put / in /la...thanks a lot!