# htaccess - Setting up a root diretory within a subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

The URL is https://subdomain.domain.com/subfolder.
But the subfolder's root folder (the folder that should be read by browsers) is 'web' and it's located in the subfolder. So the URL should be https://subdomain.domain.com/subfolder/web, but I would like it to be shown as https://subdomain.domain.com/subfolder.
How do I set up a htaccess rule in the 'subfolder'? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

It redirects only the root URL. The answer originated from this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/9992/how-to-get-apache2-to-redirect-to-a-subdirectory)

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /store/
```