# htaccess 301 redirect root to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory, http-status-code-301

Trying to get

```
www.example.com
```

to go directly to

```
www.example.com/forum
```

How can I do this with this configuration? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Right now I have added below content in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want result like

```
https://www.example.com/topic/topic-url/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/forum/topic/topic-url/
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share your tried .htaccess rules file in your question, showing efforts by Original poster of question is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Comment: "...with this configuration?" - With _what_ configuration? You've not said anything about your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Your tried rules will be creating an infinite loop hence it may not be working, I have added a condition if uri doesn't start from forum then only proceed with redirection.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/$1 [L,R=301]
```