# How to redirect the URL in AWS Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I have a small LightSail instance with wordpress installed on it. And it is a `bitnami` wordpress.

So inside the `htdocs` I have created a new folder called `blogs` and put all the files under `htdocs` there. so the new directory looks like below:

```
htdocs/
   blogs/ 
      // all the content
```

Now I have configured a domain name as well. it is `blog.somedomain.com`

When I access `blog.somedomain.com/blogs` it works fine as expected. But when I access `blog.somedomain.com`  it gives me this error page:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

[image]

How can I do this redirection? When I try to access `blog.somedomain.com` it should force direct to `blog.somedomain.com/blogs` so the error wouldn't be seen by the users.

Comment: Let me just clarify something. You have a Wordpress installed under root directory and you want extra directory called blogs and assign blog.domain.com?

Comment: No, I want to route traffic to `blog.domain.com/blogs` when I hit `blog.domain.com`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory

You can also do it in the DNS setting of your domain.

Comment: I think this has been solved in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167728/how-to-set-a-rewrite-rule-in-bitnami-wordpress 

Comment: Yes @JoseAntonioCarmona