# How to set a rewrite rule in Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I have a `bitnami` apache2 wordpress site.

my `htdocs` is in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` directory and **everything inside that has been moved to a directory** called `blogs` which is in the same `htdocs` as below:

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/
                                  /blogs
                                    - contents
```

And now when I access `blog.mydomain.com` it gives the `File permission` error as below:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

But when I access `blog.mydomain.com/blogs` I can see the content.

So, how I can **redirect from** `blog.mydomain.com` to `blog.mydomain.com/blogs` when someone hits `blog.mydomain.com`

Comment: Is there anything in the htdocs folder or are you planning to use that space for anything? Is this like double website setup?

Comment: not a double website setup. and there is nothing in the `htdocs` directory other than the `blogs` directory. And not planning on putting anything there as well.

Comment: ok, you need to change the apache2 config then - so instead of htdocs it points to htdocs/blog https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/wordpress/get-started/understand-config/
Its in the config file - I can't remember exactly where its located. The link should help.

Comment: What should I change in the apache2 config? I am new to this and have the least idea on doing this. Been trying this for hours

Comment: You need to find the document root path - it will have this `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` and just add `/blog` to it - restart apache and you are done.

Comment: Where should I add `/blog` ? should I create a directory? because it is already there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitnami developer here!

If you don't plan to use the main domain as a double website setup, you could simply perform a redirection using the `RedirectMatch` directive in your VirtualHost.

If you use the original VirtualHost setup of the instance, add the following lines to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`:

```
...
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
+ RedirectMatch ^/$ /blog/
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
  ...
</VirtualHost>
...
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
+ RedirectMatch ^/$ /blog/
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>
...
```

Explanation: When the current URL matches **the root of your domain**, `http(s)://YOUR-DOMAIN/`, the server will redirect to the second argument of the directive, `http(s)://YOUR-DOMAIN/blog`

If are using another VirtualHost setup, just place this modification there.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot. <3