# root and index.php redirect to new url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

please what I must change in this  [htaccess file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCjjZ.png) to get this?:

**example.com -> redirect -> example.com/newhp**

**example.com/index.php -> redirect -> example.com/newhp**

I tried this:

[.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^$ /newhp [L]`

and this:

`RedirectMatch ^/$ /newhp`

but it didn't work right. I guess because I need rewrite or delete something in my current htaccess.

Sorry for dump question, I am noob in this.

thanks

Comment: "but it didn't work _right_" - So, what happened exactly? Did you get an error? Nothing happened? Incorrect rewrite/redirect? The first rule (`RewriteRule`) you posted is an internal rewrite, the second (`RedirectMatch`) is a temporary redirect. What is `/newhp`? How is this handled by your server?

Comment: RewriteRule didn't do anything - no redirect. RedirectMatch gives me this error: **Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

Comment: I guess I need remove some other part of that code https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCjjZ.png, where are some redirects or rules to index

Comment: /newhp has same content as root/index.php, but I need to redirect it to /newhp

Comment: Please include the content of your existing .htaccess in the question, in text form & properly formatted, instead of showing _a screenshot_ of it. And explain/show, _where_ in that context you added the new stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead, immediately after the `RewriteBase` directive near the top of the file:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /newhp [R=302,L]
```

The uses mod_rewrite to initiate the redirect on "direct" requests to the document root only (as opposed to rewritten requests).

---

Notes about your attempts:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ /newhp [L]
> ```

This is an internal rewrite, not a redirect. You will not see a visible change in the URL. This is unlikely to work with your front-controller.

> ```
> RedirectMatch ^/$ /newhp
> ```

Note sure why this would trigger a 500 Internal Server Error - you would need to check the details in your server's error log.

This would ordinarily trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect. However, `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive so will be processed after all your existing mod_rewrite directives - despite the order of directives in your config file. This can result in unexpected conflicts.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /newhp [R=302,L]` working great! thank you very much a thanks for explanation