# Multilingual website with home and home/en subfolder point to same directory

Tags: http, multilingual

I have a Multilingual website with directory structure

```
/home
/home/en
/home/es
...
/home/xx
...
```

My domain `www.foo.com` points at `/home`. But actually `/home` has nothing under it except for the language subdirectories, which is where the HTML etc live.

I would like both `www.foo.com` and `www.foo.com/en` to point at `/home/en`. For all other languages I would like `www.foo.com/xx` to point at `/home/xx`.

I have set up a redirect to point `www.foo.com` at `/home/en`, but that doesn't work because then `www.foo.com/en` to points at `/home/en/en`.

This may all be impossible, but can I somehow default `www.foo.com` to go to `/home/en` when the language is missing, and also make `www.foo.com/xx` always go to `/home/xx`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory), its the second answer. You have to create a `.htaccess` file in your root directory with the line `RedirectMatch ^/$ /en/`. This redirects `www.foo.com` and only this domain to `/home/en`, it does not redirect `www.foo.com/en` at all.

I also wanted to redirect `http` to `https`. This is the http code that does it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch ^/$ /en/
```