# Unable to access subroutes and home page in yarn build React app

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, web-deployment, react-router-dom

I'm trying to deploy a React app to the public site and everything works ok on `localhost`. When I put the website up and go to the url (i.e. [www.something.com](http://www.something.com)), the home page renders fine including static assets.

Then, when I created an `.htaccess` file containing:

```
FallbackResource /
```

The subroutes all render fine (static assets incl js, css, images), but the home page errors with a `502 Bad Gateway`.

However, when I go to a subroute (i.e. [www.something.com/about](http://www.something.com/about)), it 404s.

- I built using `yarn build`
- I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"`
- I set up the app using `create-react-app`
- `package.json` contains `"homepage": "."`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question ended up being answered by [.htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

I redirected to the homepage as in the example and kept my FallbackResource defined.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
FallbackResource /index.html
```

I noticed you can also use any other defined route here (i.e. `/contact`)