# .htaccess URL internal Rewrite to (all)-Subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp, subdirectory

I'm currently have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /test/ [L]
```

(index.php seems to be necessary, it's from here:
[How can I use .htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/how-can-i-use-htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory#comment115796910_1328357))

System: MacBook Pro - XAMPP 8.1.2 (installer not VM)

I’m trying to rewrite not redirect (not changing adressbar), everything to `/test/`

#### This is working:

Typing in:

`localhost/`

should show content of

`localhost/test/`

#### This is not working:

with all subdirectories `localhost/test2/ -> localhost/test/test2/` …

Comment: Your RewriteRule pattern only matches a completely empty path, or one that consists of `index.php` only. `test2/` fulfills neither of those two conditions.

Comment: Hi,
thats correct, I've tried something like this `RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?(.+)$ /test/$1 [L]` but it results in an internal server error 500

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^test/ - [L]` (do nothing and end current round of rewriting, when the path already starts with `test/`), followed by `RewriteRule (.*) /test/$1 [L]`

Comment: Hi, sorry I misinterpreted that, 
it seems so work, the only thing is, 
its now an external redirect instead of an internal.
So I’ve added `(index\.php)?`
And tried this: `RewriteRule ^test/ - [L]
RewriteRule (index\.php)?(.*) /test/$1 [L]`
But now this redirects every request to `/test/` !?

Comment: Ok I've finally got it: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule (.*) /test/%1 [L]`. This works, and it's not about the index\.php its the slash at the end ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this works (as far as I understand ):

1. Prevent endless redirecting and getting path (with file (complete
   URI))

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
```

2. Rewrite everything to /subdirectory/ + requested path/file

```
RewriteRule (.*) /subdirectory/%1 [L]
```

`%1` get's URI from RewriteCond.

That's necessary 'cause `(.*)` won't give us the whole URI (path + index.html ...), it's just the path.

And the same for **nginx**:

```
if ($uri !~ "^/subdirectory/"){
    rewrite /(.*) /subdirectory$uri last;
}
```