# Hiding folder name in URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a folder in my root directory called `pages` that I would like to hide from the URL when accessed. Currently, my URL looks like this: `www.foo.com/pages/page.html`

I would like to remove the folder name `pages` in the URL but still direct users to the folder. How can I do this using the `.htaccess` file? For clarity, I would like the final URL to look like this: 
`www.foo.com/page.html`

I've taken a look at some StackOverflow answers and I am struggling to understand how I would edit my .htaccess file to make this adjustment. So far, this is what my `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

How do I change `www.foo.com/pages/page.html` to `www.foo.com/page.html` using .htaccess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use .htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/how-can-i-use-htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Comment: You simply need to `rewrite` your root folder as in the linked duplicate: `RedirectMatch ^/$ /pages/`

Comment: No, this does the opposite of what I am trying to do. What would I need to do to not display the folder name in the URL?

Comment: that does exactly that you change the root of the address so you notthat the url page.html leads directly to url/pages/page.url while not showing that folder name in the url as it is below the root then.

Comment: Could you help me understand what the .htaccess file should look like? I have no familiarity with writing .htaccess files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need 2 rules to manage this:

1. A `301/302` redirect if a URL already has `/pages/` (usually a cached URL in browsers / search results)
2. An internal (silent) rewrite to add `/pages/` at the start of URIs to serve the right page from your host

You can have these rule in your site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /pages/pages.html to /page.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages/([^\s?]*)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

## To internally rewrite /pages.html to /pages/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* pages/$0 [L]
```

Once you have verified that rules are working fine, you can then change `302` to `301` to make it a permanent redirect.

Comment: This is super insightful, I appreciate the help. I've implemented this, however, I am struggling to make this work after pushing to prod. I realized a structure issue in your response's comment (`pages.html` VS `page.html`) but I don't think that makes a difference. 

Is there anything I should add if my redirect isn't working?

`Site example: braxtonhuff.com/pages/found`

Comment: Sure. Using a page example, the redirect of `https://www.braxtonhuff.com/pages/found` is not redirecting to `https://www.braxtonhuff.com/found` – there is no hiding of the `/pages/` directory in the URL

Comment: Looks like you don't even have Apache web server. Are you sure this .htaccess is being used?

Comment: Wow this is embarrassing. I'm hosting on Vercel at this point in time and after a quick Google it looks like they don't support .htaccess files. I appreciate the insight here. Any brief thoughts on what may work as an alternative?

Comment: Sorry, I am really clueless about that since my knowledge is limited to rewrite rules, Apache and .htaccess

Comment: No problem, I just resolved this issue with Vercel rewrites. If anyone is reading this looking for a solution for Vercel domain restructuring, check out Vercel's documentation on it. `https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#rewrites`

Thanks for your help @anubhava!

Comment: Thanks for adding documentation link @braxton